# Check whether the argument of a function is a matrix with numerical values

Tags: pattern-matching

I know that

```
MatrixQ[expr,NumericQ]
```

tells whether `expr` is a matrix with numerical values or not.

How do I implement such a check for an argument of a function?

```
func[matr_?WhatShouldIWriteHere]:=Module[{},...];
```

(should only work if `matr` is a matrix with numerical values)

Comment: Any predicate is ok: just write `MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&`.  (Although you might prefer `NumberQ`.)

Comment: In addition to @Alan's comment, use parentheses, e.g., `func[matr_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := ..`